# Netbeans app runs very slowly

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm currently working on a assignment for school and I'm finished programming but I got a major issue.

When I run the program in the netbeans IDE everything works the way it should and its very smooth.

But when I try to run the Jar file it lags and my timer takes 3-5 seconds per second.

Is there something I should check before exporting the Jar file or am I running it the wrong way?

It does the same thing on my Windows 7 64 bit system, Ubuntu 12 64 bit, Ubuntu 11 64 bit and on a windows 7 32 bit. So its not a OS problem. And I do have the new java runtime

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that maybe Netbeans runs the jvm for your program with more memory. Try to run your jar with increased jvm memory settings. You know it's one of those java options like -Xmx512m when you run the `java -jar -Xmx512m yourjar.jar` at the command line.

Another guess here, Netbeans is probably executing your pure .class files instead of one packaged jar file. If you can printout the classpath, you can try executing it the same way netbeans does. It may end up where you have to deploy multiple jar files to avoid this issue. Are you using many other jar files in your code?

This is based on my experience using eclipse and having it execute things differently in the IDE versus an exported jar file.

Comment: I tried the increased jvm memory tip you gave me. But it doesnt matter if I set it on 256 of 4096. there is no difference at all :S

Comment: Print out your classpath in your code, when the program starts up. See if there's a difference when you run it in Netbeans versus when you run it at the command line in the classpath. Maybe it's using a different jar outside of netbeans that is older or slower. How big is the jar file? I wonder too if the export makes it so large it takes a long time to run. Maybe try running it with just the .class files instead of in a jar. Netbeans probably runs it not in jar form, but individual classes. The classpath well help identify that too.

Comment: In addition to Logan's suggestion, you may want to consider rolling your own jar instead of having NetBeans generate it for you. It could be that it's packaging extraneous stuff in the process, or otherwise messing with your entrypoint/main methods.

Comment: I will try that :). The jar is 1,7mb so its not a verry heavy app :P.

How do I generate my own jar file?

Answer (score 1):

The JAR is probably built with compression by default. Built your JAR manually and specify the `0` option (no ZIP compression). It's worth a try.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) for more details about the options available when creating a JAR.

Answer (score 0):

If u have eclipse INDIGO version just right click the project node and click on export, then select "Runnable JAR file" under java section click next then finish and its done!!! :)